# Spark zeppelin: how to obtain %sql result in %pyspark interpreter?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I know I can use

```
%pyspark
df = sqlContext.sql('select * from train_table')
```

And I can use `df.registerTempTable('xxx')` to make `df` accessable in `%sql` .

But sometimes I would like to use `%sql` to draw plot. Calculation may be expansive :

```
%sql
select C.name, count(C.name) from orderitems as A
left join clientpagemodules as C on C.code = A.from_module
left join orders as B on A.ref_id = B.id
left join products as P on P.id = A.product_id
where B.time_create > (unix_timestamp(NOW()) -  3600*24*30) *1000  group by C.name
```

If I decide to write some code to clean the result , I have to move above sql into `df = sqlContext.sql(sql)` , calculate again .

I wonder is there any way to access %sql result in %pyspark ?

Comment: what is `%sql` and `%pyspark` ? are you using databricks or another notebook tool ?

Comment: @Steven  Sorry, I forgot to add zeppelin tag , now added .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to do it after you have executed your sql statement, but you can access the temporary table created in %sql from %pyspark when you register it as [temporary view](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-view.html) initially:

```
%sql
--initial step
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_bla AS select * from YOURSTATEMENT

%sql
--your work as usual
Select * from temp_bla

%pyspark
--and continuing in pyspark
spark.sql('select * from temp_bla').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the SQL-table in another paragraph as a pandas Dataframe:

```
%sql(saveAs=choose_name)
SELECT * FROM your_table

%pyspark
dataframe = z.getAsDataFrame('choose_name')
```

[As written in the Zeppelin %python docs](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview1/usage/other_features/zeppelin_context.html)